# xsl is not aligning the text in middle , text-a;ign="center" and display-align="center" both are not working

Tags: xslt, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to align the text vertically in middle, have tried text-align and display-align, but both are not working for me, I'm using xsl 1.0 to print a pdf

In the table section I have generated some rows and there are some cells in each row, I'm pasting one row here just to explain my problem.

Now I tried to centre the row, centre the cell even tried centre the block, but all are useless for me.

Is there any way out there for aligning the text vertically middle in cell

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:ibex="http://www.xmlpdf.com/2003/ibex/Format">
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:template match="report">
<root xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
<layout-master-set>
<simple-page-master master-name="simple" page-width="8.27in" page-height="11.69in" margin="0.80cm">
<region-body margin-bottom=".5cm" margin-top="1cm" region-name="frontPage"/>
<region-body region-name="otherPages"/>
<region-after extent=".5cm" region-name="footer"/>
<region-before extent=".5cm" region-name="header"/>
</simple-page-master>
</layout-master-set>
<page-sequence master-reference="simple">
<flow flow-name="frontPage">
<table>
<table-column column-width="22%" column-number="1"/>
<table-column column-width="28%" column-number="2"/>
<table-column column-width="18%" column-number="3"/>
<table-column column-width="18%" column-number="4"/>
<table-column column-width="14%" column-number="5"/>
<table-body>    
<table-row background-color="#000000" color="#FFFFFF" text-align="center" align="center" display-align="center">
```

Here I'm getting the problem to align the text in middle

```
<table-cell padding-right="12pt" border-bottom="1pt solid black">
<block margin-top="10px" >Agent Name</block>
</table-cell>
<table-cell padding-right="12pt" border-bottom="1pt solid black">
<block margin-top="10px" >Agent Address</block>
</table-cell>
<table-cell padding-right="12pt" border-bottom="1pt solid black">
<block margin-top="10px">Agent Tel</block>
</table-cell>
<table-cell padding-right="12pt" border-bottom="1pt solid black">
<block margin-top="10px"  >Agent No</block>
</table-cell>
<table-cell padding-right="12pt" border-bottom="1pt solid black">
<block margin-top="10px" >ISN</block>
</table-cell>
</table-row>
</page-sequence>
<page-sequence master-reference="simple">
</page-sequence>
</root>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```